# Postfix forwarding using virtual settings

Tags: postfix, mail-command

I have gone over multiple articles which walk me through the process - I feel I understand the what and the why's - but I cannot send a email to test.

[Here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/mail_systems/postfix_documentation/VIRTUAL_README_007.html) are the steps in detail.

Here is a synopsis of the steps I took:

1. install postfix
2. create `virtual` alias file with the following:

   ```
   contact@mydomain.com alex.bXXXX@gmail.com
   ```
3. add the following lines to main.cf

   ```
   virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
   virtual_alias_domains = mydomain.com
   ```
4. `postmap virtual`
5. `postfix reload`
6. `mail -s "Test subject" contact`

The mailer client just hangs - and nothing is appended to the /var/log/mail.log or similar - only:

```
May 24 19:18:52 localhost postfix/postfix-script[12424]: refreshing the Postfix mail system
May 24 19:18:52 localhost postfix/master[4781]: reload -- version 2.11.3, configuration /etc/postfix
May 24 19:22:12 localhost postfix/postfix-script[12444]: refreshing the Postfix mail system
May 24 19:22:12 localhost postfix/master[4781]: reload -- version 2.11.3, configuration /etc/postfix
```

I am just trying to accept email for a domain - and forward it on to an real email (i.e.: gmail, yahoo, etc).

According to the book I read and every article this is pretty much the gist of the steps required - why does the client hang? What does it mean - how do I check what's going wrong when the logs say nothing?

Comment: What does `telnet localhost 25` give you? (Exit with `Ctrl+]`  then `quit`). The instructions just seem a rip-off from the official docs ( http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html ) and should be ok.

Comment: Pretty much every article on this subject is a cloned copy of the docs :) I will try telnet tomorrow. For what its worth when I used unix-users aliases worked fine. Makes me think maybe aliasing/canonical require virtual users

Comment: I am currently using virtual, but without `virtual_alias_domains` ie. mail address has to be completely specified. That works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mail -s "Test subject" contact` is "hanging" because it is waiting for input (i.e. the message to send).

Try piping some text into it:

```
echo test message | mail -s "Test subject" contact
```

or

```
mail -s "Test subject" contact < message-file.txt
```

Comment: Ugh how did I miss that? I literally copied a command off some web page saved it in my readme file for later reference but obviously that crucial part was either missed in copy or didn't save. That seems to have solved the "hanging" part. Thanks a million to you both! :)